# HTML form validation - don't validate hidden text inputs

Tags: html, forms, validation

I have a form where the user has to choose between two modes, with two individual sets of inputs. Some inputs are `required`.

```
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>This or that?</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="thisthat" value="this">
        This
            </label>
      <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="thisthat" value="that" checked>
        That
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="this"> <!-- hidden as the page loads -->
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" required="" placeholder="Some of this" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" required="" placeholder="Some more of this" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="This again" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="that">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" required="" placeholder="Some of that" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" required="" placeholder="Some more of that" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="That again" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-info" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Example on [CodePen](http://codepen.io/Demnogonis/pen/RRrdZj)

When the user fills out one part of the form the submit is prevented because of the empty fields in the other part.

How can I disable the validation for the fields in the hidden part? Preferably without removing the `required` properties of the hidden inputs.

Is there a default way to do this?